# ASP.NET MVC 4 AttributeRouting Per-Route DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I am using the nuget package http://nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/ and have specified custom routes for my web api. When I try to add a custom delegatinghandler (dh) to my routes in WebApiConfig my dh is never called. This makes sense because the dh is assigned to the default route and not assigned to the custom routes I have decorated my web api controllers with. I am able to register the dh globally and it is executed, however, I want to register the custom dh per route (different routes need to do different things and I dont want to put a massive amount of logic into one global dh).

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to do this while using the AttributeRouting package? I have searched the documentation on the site but haven't found anything.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would you please give some examples of What does your delegating handler will do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AttributeRouting website](http://attributerouting.net/#asp-net-web-api), it does not support some features under WebApi, including custom handlers. Think you might be out of luck.

> Beware! Due to integration issues with the Web API WebHost framework,
>   the following features will not work:
>
> performance enhancements when matching routes, custom route handlers,
>   querystring parameter constraints, subdomain routing, localization
>   applied to inbound/outbound urls, and lowercasing, appending prefixes,
>   etc to generated routes. These features all have to wait for vNext of
>   the Web API.

If you don't need all the extensive routing that AttibuteRouting provides, you could use your own route attribute and then register routes based on that during startup. e.g.:

```
public class RouteAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public RouteAttribute (string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

then register routes based on decorating class or action in your controller:

```
    foreach (var controllerType in controllers)
        {
        var attributes = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(controllerType);
        var uriattribute = (RouteAttribute)attributes[typeof(RouteAttribute)];
        var controllerName = controllerType.Name.Replace("Controller", "");

        string uri = uriattribute.Value;

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: controllerName,
            routeTemplate: uri,
        handler: new YourCustomHandler()
        }
    }
```

Obviously you don't want to rewrite AttributeRouting, but if your needs are simple it could be an option.

Comment: Thanks @SimonC. I don't need but two custom handlers at the moment, basically each controller needs to check authentication except for when registering for access, which credentials wouldn't be provided. I think I am going to simply register my handler globally (GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<BasicAuthMessageHandler>());) and then add some simple logic to check if a user is registering or not. As you can see though, this could get clunky if more handlers are needed down the road.

Comment: Np @crizzycrizzz. What about applying the handler globally (or as a filter globally), and then decorating non-authenticated controllers to allow anon access. Check the `[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]` attribute which does just that.

Comment: it would be dope if I could say [Handler(new MyCustomHandler())] on my routes and have AttributeRouting grab that attribute and assign it when it registers the custom routes; seems trivial.

Comment: @crizzwald, I suggest you fork [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting) and add that feature.

Comment: Scratch that.  I finally caught on that AttributeRouting has been merged into [v5 RTM of ASP.NET](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/releases/view/101957) (which is in beta). So you will want to check there for any functionality you want.